# What is the phrase for "sign[ing] in (and out)" of a website?

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique

On a website, what should be the text of a hyperlink which someone would click to "sign in" or "log in" to a site?
How about to "sign out" or "log out" of the site?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, in french we use :

- S'enregistrer / Enregistrement pour *sign in*
- Se connecter / Connexion pour *log in*

Inversement :

- Se déconnecter / Déconnexion pour *log out*

Answer (score 2):

For "sign in" there are two terms often used; they are  "**se connecter**" and "**connexion**". For "sign out" you use "**se déconnecter**" and "**déconnexion**" (see [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sign-out-sign-in.1404519/)).

These terms are used by Facebook (see the picture below);

[image]